# Question about equivalent classes.

Tags: solution-verification, recurrence-relations, relations, equivalence-relations

[image]

I have no idea what going on in this question, nor how to approach it.
From messing around with this question I found 14 pairs (i.e. (1,2),(2,1) is considered one pair) that I can add to the original set. But surely it cannot be right? Because then my options will be astronomically large..

Comment: Try considering what the equivalence classes will be when you are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a partition defines an equivalence relation and vice versa.  We may look instead at the possible partitions.

Being told that it contains $(6,6)$ is irrelevant as every equivalence relation will have this per reflexivity.

We are told that $7,4,2$ must be in the same equivalence class (*since (7,4) and (4,2) are required elements*).  We are told that $5$ must be in a different equivalence class than $4$ (*since (5,4) is a required nonelement*).  We are told that $3$ must be in a different equivalence class than both $7$ and $5$ (*since (7,3) and (3,5) are required nonelements*).  We are told that $1$ must be in the same equivalence class as $3$ (*since (1,3) is a required element*).

So... we know that there are at least three equivalence classes, $\{1,3\},\{2,4,7\},\{5\}$.  The only question is then for the remaining number $6$... whether it goes into one of these already existing equivalence classes or if it forms its own equivalence class by itself.  There are merely $4$ options.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I'm starting to get the concept of equivalent classes and quotient sets! :)